# Google Play services leaderboard sample scripts are not running

Tags: javascript, php, google-play-games

I am trying to implement Google Leaderboard for my games.

So I have downloaded sample scripts from the following URL: https://github.com/playgameservices/web-basic-samples

and put it in the web server:

E:\wamp\www\sugumar\web-basic-samples-master

and in the browser I tried

http://localhost/sugumar/web-basic-samples-master/type-a-number-js/index.html

but it showed the following error

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL
>   /sugumar/web-basic-samples-master/type-a-number-js/index.html was not
>   found on this server.

so I checked the file permissions for the folder web-basic-samples-master (I have so many projects running under sugumar folder so no problem with that folder permission).

It was in read only mode, so I unchecked the readonly and clicked on apply and on the next screen I clicked ok for "Apply changes to this folder, subfolders files" and then I clicked on ok, and then run the following url again 
http://localhost/sugumar/web-basic-samples-master/type-a-number-js/index.html

but it still shows the same problem:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL
>   /sugumar/web-basic-samples-master/type-a-number-js/index.html was not
>   found on this server.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you've skipped the entire [Running the sample application](https://github.com/playgameservices/web-basic-samples/tree/master/type-a-number-php) guide accompanying the code sample:

> To run this sample application in your own environment, perform the
>   following steps:
>
> 1.Get the latest Google APIs Client Library for PHP and extract it into your server directory.
>    - We recommend you retrieve this using git, to ensure you always have the latest version. (e.g. git clone
>   https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client)
>    - Alternately, you can get the gzip file from the downloads page. Please make sure you download version 0.6.2 or later (updated June 3,
>   2013), as the GameService contrib file does not exist in earlier
>   versions.
>
> 2.This application assumes you have PHP/MySQL already running on your server. Create a users table with the following setup:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (    `temp_key` varchar(128) NOT
> NULL,    `user_id` varchar(64) NOT NULL,    `bearer_token`
> varchar(1024) NOT NULL,    `last_modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT
> CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,    PRIMARY KEY
> (`user_id`)  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

> 3. Create your own application in the Play Console, as described in the Create Client IDs portion of the documentation. Make sure you
>      follow the "Web" instructions for creating your Client ID and linking
>      your application.
>
> If you've already set up your own version of the Type-a-Number sample
>   application, you can repurpose that application here. Either create a
>   new linked application (which will give you a new client ID), or add
>   your test server to your list of Javascript Origins in the APIs
>   Console (which will let you re-use your current client ID)
>
> 4. When you link your Web application, ensure the hostname matches the server from which you'll be testing your application. (e.g.
>      http://localhost/ or https://www.mytestserver.com). Also, make sure
>      that you have the right protocol (http vs. https)
> 5. Make a note of your Client ID and Client Secret as described in the documentation
> 6. Create a Leaderboard as described in the Leaderbords documentation. Give it a creative name like "High scores".
> 7. Once that's done, you'll want to replace the following constants defined in the SampleAppConstants.ini file.
>
> In the api section, replace the following: clientId (Replace this with
>   your OAuth2.0 Client ID) clientSecret (Replace this with your OAuth2.0
>   Client secret) In the db section, replace the following: user (Replace
>   this with your MySQL username) pass (Replace this with your MySQL
>   password) host (Replace this with your MySQL hostname) name (Replace
>   this with the name of the MySQL database you're using.) In the game
>   section, replace the following: leaderboardId (Replace this with the
>   ID of the leaderboard you created in the previous step.)
>
> 8. Move your AppConstants.ini file outside of your htdocs tree. This contains sensitive information and it shouldn't be located anywhere
>      where it could accidentally be displayed to the user.
>
>    9. Update the constructor in your GameHandler file to point to the new location of AppConstants.ini.
>
> That's it! Your application should be ready to run!